# SQLITE: Select another column if the first one is null

Tags: sqlite, select, null

I want to select the value from another column if there are no records in the first column (is null). 
I want something like this:

```
SELECT (if Column1 IS NULL THEN Column2), Column3, Column4 FROM MyTable
```

How can I do that in SQLite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`COALESCE` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce), which returns the first non-null argument:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column1, Column2), Column3, Column4
FROM MyTable
```

In this case, you will get `Column1` but if it is NULL, `Column2` will be returned instead.

Comment: @Stephan FWIW, the docs say both are equivalent, so I guess it's just a matter of semantic choice

Comment: yeah but there are some difference : 1.coalesce accepts more then 2 params 2. in the ifnull you need to know what column might be null but in coalesce you do not care since it gets the first non-null value :)

Answer (score 3):

From [Safari Books](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/9781449394592/scalar-functions/id3043664)

## Name

```
coalesce() — Return first non-NULL argument
```

## Common Usage

```
coalesce( param1, param2, ... )
```

## Description

The coalesce() function takes two or more parameters and returns the first non-NULL parameter. If all of the parameter values are NULL, a NULL is returned.

## See Also

```
ifnull(), nullif()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function , try this

```
SELECT IFNULL(Column1, Column2), Column3, Column4 FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE(column1,column2)` .

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column1, Column2), Column3, Column4 FROM MyTable
```